# django csrf mechanism with payment gateway

Tags: python, django, payment-gateway, django-csrf

I have a csrf situation that i am puzzling about.

I set my payment gateway return url to a value like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/purchased/`
i have set my urls properly and this particular one is tied to a view where i have

```
@csrf_protect
def purchased(request):
```

the problem i am facing is that when i change my return url to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/mypayments/purchased/`

I start getting a CSRF 403 forbidden error. (of course i have made the changes in my urls.py file to adjust my url to bind to the same view)

I don't understand is how changing the return url could efffect the csrf mechanism.

Comment: i forgot to mention that without the url change - i don't get the csrf error